# How do I re-size a 3D CSS Cube

Tags: html, css, 3d

I have a cube made from CSS which works fine, but when I try to make it bigger it all collapses.

The html for the cube is:

```
<section class="container"> 
    <div id="cube" class="show-front"> 
      <figure class="front">1</figure> 
      <figure class="back">2</figure> 
      <figure class="right">3</figure> 
      <figure class="left">4</figure> 
      <figure class="top">5</figure> 
      <figure class="bottom">6</figure> 
    </div> 
 </section>​
```

Here is the cube working normally, size = 200px:

```
.container {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto 40px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B3HAq/

When I try to set the size to 400px it doesn't work.

```
.container {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto 40px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D4zhK/

The size is set by changing the container width and height to 400px and then translating all sides to half the containers width 200px.

This problem is really confusing me, could anyone give me some help please. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The container seems to be the square behind the screen changing this section

```
#cube figure {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 196px;
  height: 196px;
```

}

to

```
#cube figure {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;

}
```

and then changing the transforms to 200px; seems to work.
see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B3HAq/1/)